# What does `[$'\r\n']` mean?

Tags: shell, escape-characters

I regularly use the expression `line=${line//[$'\r\n']}`. But what does `[$'\r\n']` mean?

I know it removes the `'\r\n'` characters but how does it do this? Does it remove the instances of both characters only, or does it also find matches of just one character?

I do not understand the usage of this syntax.

If you can, please, give me a link to the manual. I cannot find the answer on this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> **${*parameter*/*pattern*/*string*}**
>   The *pattern* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion. *Parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern*
>   against its value is replaced with string. The match is performed
>   according to the rules described below (see [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)). If
>   *pattern* begins with `/`, all matches of *pattern* are replaced with *string*. ... If *string* is null, matches of *pattern* are deleted and the `/` following pattern may be omitted.

You have `${line//[$'\r\n']}`, where:

- the *parameter* is `line`,
- the *pattern* is `/[$'\r\n']` (note: begins with `/`, so all matches of pattern are replaced), and
- the *string* is null, so the `/` after *pattern* is omitted, and matches are deleted.

Following the rules for [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

> **`[…]`**
>   Matches any one of the enclosed characters.

[`$'...'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) tells bash to interpret certain escape sequences (here, `\r` for carriage return and `\n` for line feed) and replace them with actual characters represented by the escape sequences.

So this substitution matches all instances of either carriage return (CR, `\r`) or line feed (LF, `\n`), and deletes them.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain what the `$'\r\n'` inside the square brackets means. Fortunately, [Michael Homer's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529938) below does.

Answer (score 8):

This command removes all carriage return and line feed bytes from the `line` variable.

This is a Bash (and zsh, and ksh) extension to parameter expansion: `${line//XYZ}` replaces *all* matches of the pattern `XYZ` in `$line` with nothing.

The pattern `[$'\r\n']` has two components: [`[...]` matches *any* of the characters inside it](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13). `$'\r\n'` is [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (another extension), and expands to the carriage return (`\r`) and line feed (`\n`) bytes, so `[$'\r\n']` is `[...]` with a carriage return and line feed inside it, and so matches both of them.

The [full manual of *shell* commands, operators, brackets, etc is here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), part of the POSIX/SUS/IEEE 1003.1 specification. The [*Bash* reference manual is here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Comment: Note that this is an instance of regular expression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression syntax, which can be found in many *nix utilities (and elsewhere), from command-line utilities like awk & sed to text editors to programming libraries like (f)lex.

Comment: @jamesqf, **no, it isn't**. The pattern in the `${var/pattern/substitution}` is a same kind of a pattern used for globbing filenames, **not** a regular expression. It's just that `[abc]` works the same in both, but try e.g. `var=abcd; echo ":${var//.*}:${var//*}:"`. See e.g. [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119906/170373) (which also includes glob patterns, and not just regexes mentioned in the question title)

Answer (score -2):

The $ means: look at the end of line for the pattern
The pattern is '\r\n'; meaning: \r (carage return) \n (new line)

The Square brackets [ ] are used to enclose what is being searched for on the individual line

Comment: No, that's not what `$'...'` means here. Michael Homer's answer explains it.